# error with merge.xts

Tags: r, xts

I am running a fairly time-consuming exhaustive backtest which involves a lot of manipulation of xts objects; if the backtest would complete it would take a day or two.

I keep encountering errors as follows

```
Error in merge.xts(x, round(y),  :
Value of SET_STRING_ELT() must be a 'CHARSXP' not a 'raw'
```

On further examination of the inputs to merge, one finds that round(y) is fine (it's a "numeric" vector), but

```
> x
Error in print.default(xx, ...) : 'getCharCE' must be called on a CHARSXP
```

At the time of the error, this particular merge has worked on (a varying number of) previous iterations of the backtest.

Previously, I also saw a similar error with 'builtin' instead of 'raw'.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to create a small (or even non-huge) reproducible example.

That the error occurs on different iterations each time, possibly suggests it is somehow related to conditions external to R. (I have plenty of ram spare.)

EDIT: Here is the output of `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.3-17 TTR_0.21-0      Defaults_1.1-1  xts_0.8-6      
[5] zoo_1.7-7      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.14.1    lattice_0.20-6
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is such an edge case, I don't think anyone will be able to help you without a reproducible example, or at least a copy of your environment that the above commands fail in.  At minimum, please provide the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @Joshua: I appreciate how useless this is as an issue/potential bug report. I have now included the output of `sessionInfo()` and will work some more on a reproducible example.